# How to automate test in ios apps

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, swift4

I am new to ios and have built an app consisting of nearly 40 view controllers.
Everything is working fine but I want to sure, so want to implement automated testing.
Anyone who knows any tool which I can employ.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode you can create a new target for your Unit and UI tests. `File -> New -> Target -> iOS Unit Testing Bundle`

I would recommend to have a good base of unit tests for your business logic and core functionality, and complement with UI tests for the basic flows and edge cases.

You can read more about automation here: https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any other way of testing, I am looking similar to robo testing of firebase testlab in ios platform. Any library ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a testable architecture, like VIPER/MVP, MVVM, MVI, then include a testing for all your logic then automate the testing with tools like:

Jenkins, Bitrise, circle-ci

If you have your repositories in Gitlab, they have Gitlab-ci
https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/

More info about continuous integration https://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html